# How can I refactor this function with reduce method? - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

This was the original function:

```
getMaxValue: function (input) {
    var maxValues = input.split(",");
    var maxValue = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < maxValues.length; i++) {
      var tempValue = parseInt(maxValues[i]);
      if (tempValue > maxValue) {
        maxValue = tempValue;
      }
    }
    return [maxValue];
  },
```

And this is me trying to use reduce instead:

```
getMaxValue: function (input) {
    let maxValues = input.split(",");
    maxValues.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
      if (currentValue > accumulator) {
        accumulator = currentValue;
      }
    }, 0);
    return accumulator;
  },
```

My task is to refactor this function with reduce method. How could I proceed with this method?

Comment: First step would be to understand what the non-reduce version does, and why. Second step would be to understand how `.reduce()` works and what it returns.

Comment: It was me who wrote the non-reduce version, so I understand it. I only have problems if reduce comes in.

Comment: My comment is purely based on the code in your question ;)

Comment: Does `input` have negative numbers?

Comment: You just need to add the `return accumulator` inside the reduce callback and assign the value returned to a variable `var maxValue = maxValues.reduce(...)`

Comment: You've removed the necessary `parseInt()` call, the `.reduce()` call doesn't return anything and modifies a variable that is only available in the callback (that's why that callback has to `return` something). The non-reduce version returns an array, the `.reduce()` version does not. All that combined: there is a lack of understanding of what the code does ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use `Math.max` along with `reduce`. or directly by spreading the values.

If you have empty strings, you could take a *`startValue`* for reducing, which is then the default value.

```js
const
    getMax1 = string => string
        .split(',')
        .reduce((a, b) => Math.max(a, b)),
    getMax2 = string => Math.max(...string.split(','));
    
console.log(getMax1('1'));
console.log(getMax2('1'));
console.log(getMax1('10,6,4'));
console.log(getMax2('10,6,4'));
```

Comment: +1 Note that `Math.max()` implicitly converts the strings to numbers, so explicit conversion is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

The reducer callback function must return the accumulator.
When sorting, the default value should be the first value, not 0
If the default value is 0 and the values are negative, it returns the wrong value: 0

You can modify getMaxValue like this:

```
getMaxValue: function(input) {
  let maxValues = input.split(",");
  const maxValue = maxValues.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
    if (currentValue > accumulator) {
      accumulator = currentValue;
    }

    return accumulator;
  }, maxValues[0]);

  return maxValue;
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some pointers that should help you write a proper refactoring:

1. You are trying to use `reduce()` as if `accumulator` was declared in
   the outer function. But that means you would *misuse* `reduce()` as
   a `forEach()`.

   Instead of relying on a shared variable, you should **use the return value**
   of `reduce()` as the reduction's result.
2. Also, your callback function is incorrect: The next value for
   the accumulator should be *returned* in the previous iteration.
   Reason is that variables (and therefore parameters, such as
   `accumulator`) of a function are unique to one call.
3. Setting the initial value to `maxValues[0]` is redundant:
   The first iteration would compare it against the first element of `maxValues`,
   itself. Instead, you should set the initial value to either 0
   (as in the original implementation), or not specify it at all to skip
   the redundant comparison.

   **Sidenote**: By using the initial value 0 **you are limiting the result** to
   0 or greater. You should use the lowest possible number: Should only
   numbers `>= 0` be valid, then 0 is fine. Otherwise you should use
   a *very small* number such as `-Infinity`.
4. Without converting to numbers, you are **comparing strings**, which
   **may produce unexpected results**. String comparison happens
   character-by-character, where the string with the first larger character
   (by code point) is considered larger:

   ```js
      // true:
      // 1. "1" (codepoint 49) is not larger than "1" (codepoint 49).
      // 2. "2" (codepoint 50) is larger than "1" (codepoint 49) -> return true.
      console.log("Actual:", "12" > "111");

      console.log("Expected:", 12 > 111);
   ```

---

To summarize, you want to:

1. Split a string into a list (of integer-containing strings).
2. Convert that list into a list of numbers.
3. Compare those numbers to get their maximum value.
4. Return that maximum value.

[An implementation with `Math.max()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74995560/13561410) would be simpler, since it covers points 2 and 3 already. Also, using provided functions such as `Math.max()` usually results in more readable and maintainable code.